# Javascript ends in Errorpage in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, module

Currenly I'm trying to animate the component module for a website for a school project. The animation contains a fadeIn/fadeOut and a change of the content without loading a whole new website. After the animation it adds a hashtag to the URL (like #about-me). In Joomla there appears only my 404 Errorpage and the animation doesn't take effect.
 It works perfectly on the HTML-Only Version and in Typo3 but not in Joomla. Google shows no result to this question, only to special plugins and modules but not for the general modules. 
How can I use it the right way? 
 You can watch the side under:
HTML: http://www.aks-schulinfo.de/gtm3_big/24h/essmann
Example of errored jQuery: http://www.aks-schulinfo.de/gtm3_big/24h/essmann/js/dynamicpage.js
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contentchange without reloading is now working fluently, thank you! The other half (the fades) are still not working. 
Why does the fadeeffect apply at the html-only view but not in at the Joomla site?


Links:
HTML-Only: www.aks-schulinfo.de/gtm3_big/24h/essmann/htmlonly 
Joomla-version: www.aks-schulinfo.de/gtm3_big/24h/essmann/

Comment: Looks like a linking issue. The Joomla site links to [this](http://www.aks-schulinfo.de/gtm3_big/24h/js/dynamicpage.js) JS file which doesn't exist and the HTML site links to [this one](http://www.aks-schulinfo.de/gtm3_big/24h/essmann/htmlonly/js/dynamicpage.js), which does.

Comment: They both exist, but just the onlyhtml-version file is viewable... The joomla-version code, which errors in a 404 is there and perfectly linked but gets blacked out by joomla and I have no reason why...!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you'd like to change the page's content without reloading the page. One of the easiest ways to do this is to load all of the content on the page, and then hide everything that's unrelated. So, setgup your index.php page (or which ever is your main) with all of the content separated into their own divs.

```
<div id="contentHome"> .... </div>
<div id="contentAnmeldung"> .... </div>
<div id="contentRegelwerk"> .... </div>
<div id="contentSitempa"> .... </div>
```

Use javascript to find the current hash tag with [location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp), then switch the possibilities and show related content while hiding the other three. If you're really gung-ho, you can do the same with php as the page is being created so that people can link to specific "pages" still.

NOTE: This works well with limited content like the site currently has. Don't even try it if you have a lot of content because page load times will be horrendous.